# Convergence of a sequence of measure distribution functions

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to show that for $f$ and $f_n$ measurable, $|f_n|\uparrow|f|$ implies $d_{f_n}\uparrow d_f$, where $d_f(\alpha)$ is the distribution function given by $$d_f(\alpha):=\mu(\{x: |f(x)|>\alpha\})$$ Any help as to what direction to take with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The events $A_n:=\{x:|f_n(x)|>\alpha\}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, form an increasing sequence with limit $\cup_n A_n=\{x:|f(x)|>\alpha\}$. Now invoke the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I've got it.

Comment: This is a measure theory question, not a harmonic analysis or Fourier analysis question. Please use tags appropriately in the future.

Comment: Matt, this is a question from a book titled "Fourier Analysis", so clearly the tag wasn't that inappropriate.